# Setting different "ticketСache" or "keytab" parameters for different hive jdbc

Tags: jdbc, hive, kerberos, dbeaver

I use DBeaver (windows) to connect to different hive servers (Kerberos Auth)

Connection 1 is

`jdbc:hive2://<server_address_1_ip>:<port>/main;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=some.realm.com;KrbHostFQDN=<server_address_1_ip>;KrbServiceName=hive;KrbAuthType=2;SocketTimeout=0;useTicketCache=true;ticketCache=C:\Users\<my_username>\krb5cc_<tech_user_1>;renewTGT=true;doNotPrompt=true;principal=<tech_user_1>@some.realm.com`

Connection 2 is

`jdbc:hive2://<server_address_2_ip>:<port>/main;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=some.realm.com;KrbHostFQDN=<server_address_2_ip>;KrbServiceName=hive;KrbAuthType=2;SocketTimeout=0;useTicketCache=true;ticketCache=C:\Users\<my_username>\krb5cc_<tech_user_2>;renewTGT=true;doNotPrompt=true;principal=<tech_user_2>@some.realm.com`

I want to connect to this servers at same time and don't matter how it will be (using "ticketСache" or "keytab" for example)

Now, in order to connect, I need to initialize the ticket (kinit <tech_user_1>/<tech_user_2>), restart the application, but only one of the two connections will be used.

When I don't have valid ticket, DBeaver show error: "Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication". I think DBeaver ignore some parameters from jdbc connection url.

Comment: check the jdbc documentation for the distribution of driver you are using,
as far i know there is no option like ticketCache in opensource 
https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-4.0.0-alpha-1/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/Utils.java

Answer (score 0):

When I use driver provided by cloudera I see krbJAASFile option in DriverSetting page of DBeaver. You can try the same. My jaas conf looks like below:

```
Client {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="/Users/raid/hive_jdbc_logs/raid.keytab"
principal="raid@some.realm.COM"
doNotPrompt=true;
};
```

And url format is:

```
jdbc:hive2://<server_address_fqdn>:<port>;AuthMech=1;KrbHostFQDN=<server_address_fqdn>;KrbRealm=some.realm.COM;KrbServiceName=hive
```

[image: Driver settings]

Comment: My driver dont have param krbJAASFile param

Comment: then better contact / buy Dbeaver supported version. there are many ways to do this like adding java params to each connection referring to particular jaas file

Comment: i wil try to do this